# UI loses data-bindings

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I'm using Durandal framework to develop a web-site. UI has data bindings via knockout.js.
Sometimes accidently I encounter the following problem:
UI elements lose subscriptions to model data (computed values), so UI doesn't update, when it normally would. Still, the binded computed properties change correctly - the case is the lost binding to UI itself.
Debugger revealed, that at the moment after changing property, inner knockout subscriptions collection is empty.

--

Ok, adding some code, though I'm sure it won't tell anything.
widget controller:

```
define(function () {
    var model = function (element, settings) {
        var self = this;

        this.widget = settings.widget;

        var staticTitle = this.widget.staticTitle;
        this.contentTitle = ko.observable('');
        this.title = ko.computed(function () {
            var dynamicTitle = (self.widget.title && self.widget.title());
return (dynamicTitle ? staticTitle + ': ' + dynamicTitle : staticTitle);
        });
```

widget view:

```
<div data-bind="template: { afterRender: afterRender }" class="widget ui-widget-content">
    <div class="ui-widget-header" id="__header" data-bind="text: title"></div>
    <button class="close" data-bind="click: close">&times;</button>
    <div class="widget-content">
        <!--ko widget: { kind: widget.kind, model: widget } --><!--/ko-->
    </div>
</div>
```

So, __header is the element that is binded to title() computed value.
In some other place I change title by changing underlying widget's title:

```
title(someValue);
```

The fact is, that computed title property, that shall be binded to UI, is updated properly. As expected. But it is NOT reflected in UI SOMETIMES (~1/10 chance). All this happens after switching the view, with transition enabled.
Investigation showed, that at the moment of changing that property DOM contains previous view, with no trace of 'current' elements, including the one being binded.

Comment: Please post some code! Without it, it is impossible to find out what could be your actual problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution myself. The problem was caused by Durandal transition. This effect somehow affected DOM generation, and it was not ready at the moment of data-binding. So knockout tried to subscribe UI elements, that did not actually exist. When they were finally ready, 'binding' was already performed, having 0 subscriptions

Comment: You will have to use promises to get around these sorts of async issues. I'm pretty sure Durandal uses them. http://blog.mediumequalsmessage.com/promise-deferred-objects-in-javascript-pt1-theory-and-semantics

Comment: Well, that's the thing Durandal must do. I don't use any kind of manual data-binding, so this is Durandal who should bind UI. And sometimes it does it before DOM is ready, therefore ruining binding. This isn't a 'special' feature... Even if durandal uses promises, it uses it incorrectly.

Comment: Yea, fair enough.  Just a thought though, have you tried putting your subscription code in the ViewAttached callback?  http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks/

Comment: I don't agree with your answer.  The transition is not preventing the DOM from being ready nor is it preventing data-binding.  In fact, the transition does not take place until the DOM is ready.  The problem (which we cannot help verify because you did not provide any code to back up your point) is that you are trying to manipulate the DOM without utilizing Durandal's coding conventions like Nathan mentioned, therefore you are seeing problems.

Comment: Added code, as several asked... Don't see any point of it, but as you wish. As for viewAttached callback, this is one of the ways I tested the elements availability. 'have you tried putting your subscription code': Nathan, this should be done automatically, not by hooking various callbacks, shouldn't it? I'd rather switch off the feature. 'you are trying to manipulate the DOM ': i'm NOT trying to manipulate DOM. I used it to verify the error, which appear in standard case. I posted some code above, so if I violated any Durandal conventions, please tell me.